# Running a persistent live Ubuntu USB on Macbook Pro 16 inch 2019

Tags: 20.04, live-usb, macbook

I downloaded Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, created a persistent live USB using `mkusb`.
The boot-up process works fine,  no issue with keyboard and mouse.... only the WiFi adapter wasn't working .. so i tethered on my mobile phone.

***Correction*** Am using an external keyboard and mouse thus not affected, seems the macbook keyboard + mouse is still not working. Have also installed a USB wireless dongle to get wireless

Launch `snap-store`, it loads but i can't see any installed program listed..
So as per usual practice i will do an apt-update and apt-upgrade, worked fine for previous 18.04 persistent live USB i had..... but this time round after the upgrade is complete, the snap-store won't load anymore.. you get errors like `permission denied /run/usr/0` when invoking it from terminal

Edit 1:

As requested... I'm unable to launch the `Ubuntu Software`, after performing `apt update` and `apt upgrade`.. **after reboot**...when launching from console:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ sudo snap-store
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/run/user/0’: Permission denied
Warning: Schema “org.gnome.system.locale” has path “/system/locale/”.  Paths starting with “/apps/”, “/desktop/” or “/system/” are deprecated.
Warning: Schema “org.gnome.system.proxy” has path “/system/proxy/”.  Paths starting with “/apps/”, “/desktop/” or “/system/” are deprecated.
Warning: Schema “org.gnome.system.proxy.http” has path “/system/proxy/http/”.  Paths starting with “/apps/”, “/desktop/” or “/system/” are deprecated.
Warning: Schema “org.gnome.system.proxy.https” has path “/system/proxy/https/”.  Paths starting with “/apps/”, “/desktop/” or “/system/” are deprecated.
Warning: Schema “org.gnome.system.proxy.ftp” has path “/system/proxy/ftp/”.  Paths starting with “/apps/”, “/desktop/” or “/system/” are deprecated.
Warning: Schema “org.gnome.system.proxy.socks” has path “/system/proxy/socks/”.  Paths starting with “/apps/”, “/desktop/” or “/system/” are deprecated.
09:35:42:0334 GLib-GIO g_app_info_get_name: assertion 'G_IS_APP_INFO (appinfo)' failed
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
09:35:42:0371 Gtk cannot open display: :0
```

Comment: Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1303885/edit) your question and post the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

If your partition for persistence (labeled `writable` or `casper-rw`) is too small, it will get full by

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

and that will create severe problems.

Otherwise, for example in a drive with 32 GB, there should be drive space enough for all the added files after running those commands.

I suggest that you try again, either by making a fresh installation of your persistent live system, or by booting your Ubuntu system live-only, and removing all directories and files from the partition for persistence (labeled `writable` or `casper-rw`) and try again without updating and upgrading.

If you want an updated and upgraded system there are two alternatives:

1. Download the [current daily iso file of Focal Fossa from the iso testing tracker](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/408/builds/224865/downloads) and create a persistent live drive from it.
2. Download a [compressed image of an installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS) and extract and clone it to a drive with at least 16 GB. Such a system can be updated and upgraded just like a system installed to an internal drive.

   See also the following links and links from them.

   - [My two posts in this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2447539)
   - [Step-wise instructions for installed system in a USB drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312)

Comment: thanks for the alternative, but i tried this on a 64gb usb with 80% persistence... don't think its a disk space issue..

Comment: thanks for the alternatives, those are full installs which will probably work out but the persistent live approach still wouldn't work

Comment: @belgeran, My first guess was wrong, there is another problem with the persistent live system. - Did you download the [current daily iso file of Focal Fossa from the iso testing tracker](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/408/builds/224865/downloads) and create a persistent llive drive from there?

Comment: have tested using the daily iso file, and created a persistent live from there.. that works fine because there's really not much to apt upgrade from...?

Comment: @belgeran, the current daily iso file is up to date, so there is nothing to upgrade. After a day or two, there will probably be some upgrades available ... Anyway, I'm asking: did it solve your problem?

Comment: yup it kinda mitigated the problem, since there wasn't any upgrade?.... i believe its the snap-store upgrade that broke the pathing and while this download resolves the issue by being already up to date.... i'm just of the mind that a future apt upgrade of snap-store will still cause the pathing issue

Comment: @belgeran, Maybe, maybe not. It depends what kind of upgrades there are to come, and if they are compatible or not. - You may try with a full install in an external drive (e.g. USB pendrive) because ugrades are more tested in such a system and therefore more likely to work properly.